# Collation error because of emulating of prepared statements truned off

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'latin1_general_cs' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'

This error popped up when I added this line to my options array that I use when connecting to the database

```php
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false
```

And eventually it disappeard when I removed this part `COLLATE latin1_general_cs` from this line

```php
$select = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_data WHERE email = :email COLLATE latin1_general_cs");
```

The proplem is that I want to make the search in the database case sensitive and also wanna turn the emulation of the prepared statements off, but once I turn it off, I can not use case sensitive collation in my select query.

Comment: your charset is already binary which is case sensitive by definition. why this collate?

Comment: I already thought that, but when I remove the collate it becomes case insensitive, how I knew? In my website when the user enters email to sign up I check if this email is in the database already, if yes I prevent the user from using it again, when I tried these two emails `asd@asd.asd` and `Asd@asd.asd` without the collate it thought they are the same, but with the collate they are different.

Comment: Try it with `SELECT * FROM users_data WHERE BINARY email = :email`

Comment: It worked already without any cargo cult operators

Comment: on a side note, emails asd@asd.asd and Asd@asd.asd ARE the same. if you send an email to these two addresses it will come to the same mailbox. I have no idea why you would allow these two emails if you need them unique.

Answer (score 0):

> when I remove the collate it was case insensitive

This is a claim that **needs to be proven**. Especially when you ask a question on Stack Overflow.

For this, you have to provide a code that proves your point. A code like this.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $dsn  = 'mysql:charset=utf8;dbname=test;host=localhost;charset=utf8';
    $opt  = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    );
    $db =$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$db->query("create temporary table tr (t varchar(20) character set binary)");
$db->query("insert into tr values ('aaa')");
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT t from tr where t=?");
$stmt->execute(['AAA']);
var_dump($stmt->fetchColumn());
```

**Obviously**, this code returns **false**.

This code is called MCVE and this method is called [debugging](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve). It helps you to ground your conclusions not on random thoughts but on **solid facts**.

Every time you have an idea that some your code doesn't work as expected, you have to write a code to either prove or disprove the notion. In case it is disproved, your problem solved. In case it is proved, you have a ready made code to provide along with your question on Stack Overflow to make it **on topic**.

Comment: I have already proven that it is case insensitive without the collate, when i used the two emails `asd@asd.asd` and `Asd@asd.asd`, and in return the server told me that the second email is already in the database which proves that it is case insensitive.

Comment: You didn't. You only can prove anything with **an isolated working code example.**